# Java Log ==> JTextArea

Tags: java, logging, jtextarea

**Need:** Output a Java application's log into a GUI component, such as a JTextArea.

**Concern:** Need to log things from any class, in a static manner. However, the GUI logger component must not be static (obviously) as it's the member of a parent component.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a singelton log provider and add the "textfield" as a listener to it.

Example of the logger singelton:

```
interface Listener {
    void log(String log);
}

enum Logger {

    instance;

    private List<Listener> listeners = new LinkedList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener l) {
    synchronized(listeners) {
        listeners.add(l);
     }
    }

    public void log(String log) {
        synchronized(listeners) {
            for(Listener l : listeners)
                l.log(log);
        }
    }
}
```

Add your listener (which you will need to implement yourself) like this:

```
Logger.instance.addListener(myTextField);
```

And use it (from any class) like this:

```
Logger.instance.log("Hello World!");
```

Or you can use a package like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j).

Comment: Don't write yet another logging framework, just don't do it.  Use log4j (or slf4j, it seems to be all the rage)

Comment: I disagree, do not add another dependency if you want to do something this simple..

Answer (score 1):

Log to a file, have the component follow the tail of the file.  You probably want to use log4j's XML logging if you want to put the output into a grid.

**Update:** You could alternatively implement an in-memory circular logger.

Comment: good call -- this decouples the timing/priority requirements. Logging should be high-priority, displaying the log should not.

Answer (score 0):

Databinding comes to my mind. You need a *model* that represents your log and this model is bound to a GUI component. A common databinding framework for SWT is JFace Databinding, I'm sure something similiar exists for SWING.

How would it work - the logger adds messages to the model, maybe just an Arraylist of Strings (logentries). The databinding classes listen to the model and update the GUI everytime the model has changed. It would work the other way round too (edits on the GUI could be send to the model) but you'll just need one direction.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for circular dependencies between your classes and packages, you don't want spaghetti code.

My Swing application exists out of 9 modules (controller, application, platform, utils, model, persistence, service, logger, and view)

Here are dependencies:

```
view -> logger, controller, utils, model
controller -> logger, application, model, utils
application -> service, model, utils, platform
service -> persistence, model, utils
platform -> model
utils -> no dependencies
model -> no dependencies
logger -> model, utils
```

A desired dependency is from view to controller but not from controller to view.

So the best is to add a module logger and create a handler (which is an observable) which notifies observers (view like JFrame, JFace = observers).

View and service (place where you want to trigger observer) module aren't dependent on each other but through logger module.

But I think the databinder works also that way. I guess except you are framework dependent. My solution is not, so if I want to switch from Swing to swt, no worries, I just implement it for swt, and my business logic remains intact.

You should all think more design wise. (And use maven.)